# F# function arguments type annotation not working

Tags: function, f#, arguments, type-annotation

I want to have a specific type for an argument in a F# function:

```
type NewType = string*int

let testFunction (arg1:NewType) : NewType =
  ("resultString", 2)

testFunction ("test", 3)
```

I want the type of the function to be:

```
NewType -> NewType
```

But the function type is:

```
string*int -> NewType
```

What should I do to enforce the type of the argument arg1 to be "NewType"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type NewType = string * int` is what is called a type abbreviation. It gives a name or alias to another type, but it gets erased during compilation. There is no encapsulation, no new reference and basically no new type at all.

It can serve as documentation, but F#'s compiler treats the new name and the aliased type the same. This is especially visible if you make a DLL with a public function/method which is using `NewType` and try to call it from another project - you will see mixed result like in your case.

This may not be a problem if what you want to achieve is just better readability. If I see `let testFunction (arg1:NewType) : NewType = ...` in the code, especially on the web like on GitHub, where there are no IntelliSense tooltips, this still gives me pretty good idea what the function takes and returns, even if the "real" type in practice is `string * int`.

If you want better type safety, the usual practice is defining a single-case discriminated union which you can combine with pattern matching like this:

```
type NewType = NewType of (string * int)

let testFunction (NewType arg1): NewType =
    NewType ("resultString", 2)

testFunction (NewType ("test", 3))
```

You can read more here, and in other articles from the series: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-abbreviations/

Comment: But why does the return type is "NewType", why does it work with the return type and not with the argument. By the way thanks for the link!

Comment: @FraK, that's a good question, to which I don't know a satisfactory answer other than: that's how the current version of the compiler decided to do it (source for example: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/717). As Tomas nicely put it, the original type and its alias are interchangeable for the compiler (and other tooling), and it makes no guarantees as to when will you see one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

The type declaration of `NewType` is a type alias, meaning that `NewType` is exchangeable with `string * int` - the compiler treats them as the same thing and sometimes this means that it will report one in place of the other despite having a type annotation.

If you want a type that always has to be referred to via its full name, you'll need to define it as an explicit new type - at this point, it's probably best to use a record (which will also let you name the individual fields), but if you want something terse, you could use a single-case discriminated union instead:

```
type NewType = NT of (string*int)

let testFunction (NT arg1) : NewType =
  NT("resultString", 2)

testFunction (NT("test", 3))
```

Comment: But then why does the return type always work, it is "NewType" and not the string*int ?

Comment: @FraK I think it is merely a side-effect of some implementation detail in the compiler - when unifying two types `t1` and `t2`, the compiler checks if they are equal - and then picks and uses one of them as the type name it shows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer